# How to record pairs of index values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a string that contains the (linearized) secondary structure information (RNA_SS) and a string that contains sequence (RNA_seq). The "<" and ">" symbols represent base pairing between nucleotides, as demonstrated in the schematic.

RNA_SS =  "..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>."

RNA_seq = "..AAUGCCCCAUU..CCAAGG."

[2D schematic of RNA secondary structure. Bolded nucleotides are base-paired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAQGX.png)

As described in RNA_SS, the first "<" and last ">" (before another "<") symbol are a base pair and it works inward from there until you reach the last "<" (before a ">") and the first ">". I would like to store these paired indexes together so I can go back and look at the nucleotides in those positions.

I think a dictionary would work best for base pair output but I'm not married to that being the final output form. I would like a output similar to as follows:

`bps = {2:12, 3:11, 4:10, 5:9, 13:18 , 14:17}`

My strategy right now is to identify places with a "<" symbol and log the indexes a keys without a value. Later, I will then add in the corresponding ">" values as the keys. I have the code below, which returns `{14: None}`.

```
bps={}

for idx,sym in enumerate(RNA_SS):
        if sym == "<":
                bps=dict.fromkeys([idx])
print(bps)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below:

```
# test case
test =  "..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>."

# find all indices
all_lt = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(test) if ltr == '<']
all_gt = [i for i, ltr in enumerate(test) if ltr == '>']

# match the gt (>) to lt(<)
match = {}
for gt in all_gt:
    key = max([i for i in all_lt if i < gt and i not in match. Keys()])
    match[key] = gt
# Output: {5: 9, 4: 10, 3: 11, 2: 12, 16: 19, 15: 20}
```

The algorithm is:

1. find all indices of greater than > and less than < signs
2. for every '>' sign try to match it with appropriate '<' sign: the one which is nearest to the index of the '>' (max(...)) and not already taken (not in the match dictionary)

You can also sort the dictionary by keys if you like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

sorted_match = OrderedDict(sorted(match. Items()))
# Output: OrderedDict([(2, 12), (3, 11), (4, 10), (5, 9), (15, 20), (16, 19)])
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... My strategy right now is to identify places with a "<" symbol and log the indexes a keys without a value. Later, I will then add in the corresponding ">" values as the keys. ..."*

You can iterate on each character, and stem a new, inner *for-loop* for every `<` character encountered.
The subsequent *for-loop* will iterate, keeping a count of both `<` and `>` characters, only adding the indices when the count is 0.

This will produce a list of *tuple* values.

```java
RNA_SS = "..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>."
values = []
for indexA, characterA in enumerate(RNA_SS):
    if characterA != '<':
        continue
    count = 1
    for indexB, characterB in enumerate(RNA_SS[indexA + 1:]):
        if characterB == '<':
            count += 1
        elif characterB == '>':
            count -= 1
            if count == 0:
                values.append((indexA, indexA + indexB + 1))
                break
```

Output

```
[(2, 12), (3, 11), (4, 10), (5, 9), (15, 20), (16, 19)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question of finding base pairs in the RNA secondary structure in quite similar to the problem of finding balanced parentheses. The problem is usually solved using a stack (a kind of data structure). For example, you could check [Valid Parentheses](https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/)
 on LeetCode for more information.

This is a function to find matching base pairs.

```py
def extract_base_pairs(RNA_SS):
    """Extract base pairs from RNA (linearized) secondary structure information.

    If RNA_SS is not properly balanced, return an empty dict.
    """
    base_pairs = dict()
    stack = []

    for i, symbol in enumerate(RNA_SS):
        if symbol == "<":
            # put (i, symbol) into stack. for example, (2, "A").
            stack.append((i, symbol))
        elif symbol == ">":
            # first, ensure stack is not empty.
            if len(stack) == 0:
                # there is error, just return an empty result.
                print("error: the provided RNA_SS is not properly paired.")
                print(f"at i = {i}") # f"xxx" is a formatted string.
                return {}
            # next, check the symbol on the top of stack is "<".
            start_i, start_symbol = stack.pop()
            if start_symbol == "<":
                # properly paired symbols.
                base_pairs[start_i] = i
            else:
                # the symbol is not paired.
                print("error: the provided RNA_SS is not properly paired.")
                print(f"at i = {i}")
                return {}
    if len(stack) != 0:
        print("error: the provided RNA_SS is not properly paired.")
        print("after processing the whole sequence, the stack is not empty.")
        return {}
    return base_pairs
```

Use the function on the example RNA_SS and RNA_seq.

```py
RNA_SS = "..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>."
RNA_seq = "..AAUGCCCCAUU..CCAAGG."

base_pairs = extract_base_pairs(RNA_SS)
print("base_pairs = ", base_pairs)

for i, j in base_pairs.items():
    print(((i, j), RNA_seq[i], RNA_seq[j]))
```

Output

```
base_pairs =  {5: 9, 4: 10, 3: 11, 2: 12, 16: 19, 15: 20}
((5, 9), 'G', 'C')
((4, 10), 'U', 'A')
((3, 11), 'A', 'U')
((2, 12), 'A', 'U')
((16, 19), 'C', 'G')
((15, 20), 'C', 'G')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack to store the indices of the left brackets, and pop the stack as a key for the output dict when you encounter a right bracket, with the then current index as the pairing value for the output:

```
RNA_SS = "..<<<<...>>>>..<<..>>."
lefts = []
bps = {}
for index, char in enumerate(RNA_SS):
    if char == '<':
        lefts.append(index)
    elif char == '>':
        bps[lefts.pop()] = index
print(bps)
```

This outputs:

```
{5: 9, 4: 10, 3: 11, 2: 12, 16: 19, 15: 20}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/BoringDramaticCpu